# T-SQL TRANSACTION wrapped around a query - question on table locks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, insert, truncate

I wrote a stored procedure that will `TRUNCATE` then `INSERT` a dataset into a table.

The dataset is constructed from a series of CTEs that ping all sorts of tables/dbs, across 2 different servers.

I have 2 ways I could write this. One with a temp table, and one without:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MyTempTable;

...
 <Series of CTEs that build the dataset - some of the things pinged are production systems>
...

SELECT * FROM CTE_FINAL INTO #MyTempTable

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable

    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable 
        SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This way requires a temp table - but the advantage is that the transaction only occurs right at the end, thus minimizing table locks.  (Is that right, or am I talking out of my hat?)

Or I could do it without a temp table - that much simpler.  But doesn't this extend the table locks, since the `TRANSACTION` starts before all the CTE code is run?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable

    ...
    <Series of CTEs that build the dataset - some of the things pinged are production systems>
    ...

    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable 
        SELECT * 
        FROM CTE_Final

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The whole thing runs in < 5 seconds either way. But as a general practice, which way is better?

Comment: A CTE is not "run" before the query that uses it - it's merely a definition - like a view - that's used by the optimizer at compile time to construct the final query; putting your begin tran before or after the CTE will not (afaik) make any difference, the same work is done in the transaction. That said, your first way is better as it minimises the work done within the transaction.

Comment: Side note in fully supported SQL Server versions you can use `drop table if exists`

Comment: @Stu why is minimizing the work done within the transaction, better?

Comment: @Stu - thanks, drop table is exists is cleaner

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable `  is better to be out side of Tx block.
It never introduct a transaction processing.